# How to add more than two columns to handle a polymorphic relationship in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

Default polymorphic relationship in Laravel is handled by two columns id and type.

```
eg. commendable_id,commentable_type
```

What if I want to add four columns instead of two in my comments table.

```
commentable_id, commentable_type, commentedby_id(a user id),commentedby_type(a user type)
```

Does Laravel allow us to add four columns? Is there any way to implement this concept.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have multiple different models for your users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create 2 separate polymorphic relationships, one for commentable, one for commentedby.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it would be good if someone can suggest me a way by which I can handle it by one table.

Comment: A polymorphic relationship doesn't require any extra tables, unless you need to do a many-to-many relationship. If I misunderstood your requirements, please post the exact tables with columns, and how'd you like to link them up.

Comment: Can you please explain how@Tudor

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->morphToMany(SomeClass::class, 'relation', 'relations_table')
->where('connection_type', '3_field')
->where('something', '4_field')
```